# How can I make SuperPuTTY open a new session in a tab instead of a separate window?

Tags: windows, putty, superputty

I have been using SuperPuTTY on Windows 11 to manage multiple PuTTY sessions using tabs. I find this to be much more convenient than having multiple PuTTY windows cluttering the screen.  However, I accidentally got into a mode where every new session popped up in a separate window.  How can I get back to the original behavior of using multiple tabs for multiple PuTTY sessions?

Answer (score 0):

The answer I found was the "Session" field (just to the right of the "Password" field). Click the drop-down menu and select "Default Settings" (it was blank when I was getting the "separate window" behavior).

This restored the original behavior of opening a new PuTTY session in a new tab, instead of a separate window.